# Where did the production environment get its name?

Tags: definition, production

Many software development teams use the term `production` to refer to the live environment accessed by their users.  Rails for example uses [this nomenclature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production).  The string production is also used by [express](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L83).

The [dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/production) of `production` however doesn't seem to easily lend its self to this usage.  Is there an alternate definition I'm missing, or did some earlier project establish this standard?

Comment: While an interesting question, I think this question will be more suitable on Super User.

Comment: Definition 1b2 seems right on the mark to me. "...a work presented to the public."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a factory, the "production line" is where the actual product is made (or you could say "the goods are produced")

Hence "production" is "where we make the thing we sell to the user".  Move that idea to comapnies where the thing being sold is a service and the principle holds...